# How to compare two files and extract some data with Python

Tags: python

I have 2 files: file1, file2. file2 contains all of file1 and many more. Example:

```
file1:
data1/111 
data2/222 
data3/333 

file2:
data1/111 \ewr\xcgf\wer 54645623456.xml
data23/42234 \asdqw\aqerf 23525.xml
data2/222 \asd\qwe 234234.xml
data66/2331 \a53\fdf355 12312333311.xml
data3/333 \from\where 123123.xml
data4/444 \xcv\sdf\ghf 98546.xml 
and MANY more...
```

So, I'm trying to print out the lines which exist on both files BUT from file2. Which means print out must have the extra data in every line. Like the path and the XML file name.

I've tried;

```
lines1 = open(path1).readlines()
lines2 = open(path2).readlines()

for i in lines1:
    for j in lines2:
        if i in j:
            print(j.rstrip())
```

This prints all the lines at `lines2` but what I'm trying to find out is; search the first line from `lines1` in `lines2` and if finds it anywhere in `lines2`, print that line from `lines2`, so and so forth. So after that it should do the same for the second line in `lines1`

Can anyone help?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use .readlines() instead of .read().split()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for Cross-Check;

```
lines1 = open(path1).readlines()
lines2 = open(path2).readlines()

for i in lines1:
    for j in lines2:
        if j.startswith(i.rstrip()):
            print(j.rstrip())
            break
```

What this does: searches 1 line from `lines1` against all the lines from `lines2`. `break` prevents the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

```
lines1 = open(path1).readlines()
lines2 = open(path2).readlines()

for l1 in lines1:
    if l1 in lines2:
        print(l1)
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
lines1 = open(path1).readlines()
lines2 = open(path2).readlines()
print([line for line in lines1 if line in lines2])
```

Comment: @Leustad: The post was edited while you were commenting, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not really clear, but if you know you have the same lines but with more data in some cases for file2, you can just do the following for an *O(n)* solution:

```
lines1 = open(path1).readlines()
lines2 = open(path2).readlines()

for line1, line2 in zip(lines1, lines2):
    if line1 != line2:
        print line2.rstrip()
```

Comment: This is a good solution if you want to ensure that the positions of the lines are respected (line 4 and line 3 will not be treated equal even if they're identical)

Comment: I think this works but i have no idea why there is an empty line between prints.

Comment: Because readlines does not strip the trailing newline. Try now

Comment: What if the line orders are different in files?

Comment: @enrico.bacis I believe this checks line by line but not cross check. How can i make it to check the 1st line in `lines1` against all the lines at `lines2` so and so forth...

Comment: @Leustad: exactly, that's the meaning of *if you know you have the same lines but with more data*.